# trying to get a node.js project to connect to a javascript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get node.js to send information back to a website I'm trying to get information from [here](https://discbottest-2.mathman05.repl.co) (rn its a temp a value) but how would I get the information using javascript? or do I need to change something in the node.js project

```js
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/', (req, res) => 
{
  console.log("tried")
res.send({"body":"important info"});
//the info passed on can't be a number
}
);
  app.listen(3000);
```

when I tried

```
fetch("https://discbottest-2.mathman05.repl.co")
.then(r => r.json())
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);
```

it would error: "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably having issues with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). In express it is easy to disable for development using the cors npm module. After you install it using `npm install cors` something like this should help you solve the problem

```js
const app = require('express')();
app.use(require("cors")());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("tried")
    res.send({ "body": "important info" });
    //the info passed on can't be a number
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the port on the fetch call, so it will be:

```
fetch("https://discbottest-2.mathman05.repl.co:3000/")
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```